# Generating a travel time to health facilities raster surface using R

Tags: r, gis

I am trying to generate a Travel time to health facilities in r using the
`gdistance`package in R. I have already implemented this in ArcGIS 10.1 using the path Distance algorithm that is able to account for differences in land cover and elevation (while including Tobler's hiking function). Does anyone know if it can be implemented and how?